# magento Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted

Tags: database, core-config-data

[![enter image description here][1]][1]please visit this link : **http://sitename.com/**

```
i am using full path in core_config_data : http://sitename.com/
```

I chnaged new domain in core_config_data table , than all this error

i am seeing this : **llegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted**

```
Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(773): Zend_Uri::factory('??http://videom...')
#1 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(332): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#2 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->_checkBaseUrl(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#3 /var/www/html/sitename/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#4 /var/www/html/sitename/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/sitename/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#6 {main}
```

Comment: check there is space before the url?

Comment: i removed cache, its working , now showing blank page.

Comment: check the error log..

Comment: 2016-01-08T07:29:37+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected  in /var/www/html/videomergerapp/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php on line 363

Comment: there is showing 1 did you use any exit?

Comment: i dont think so, i remember i did't used that

Comment: check the page source you can see.. your admin is working. then code problem in frontend.

Comment: yes , from where it  is coming ? i  have no idea

Comment: there is not exception log? enable the error_display from index.php

Comment: i am using this : "ini_set('display_errors', 1);" i removed "#" but still no error...

Comment: login to admin panel and refresh ur cache

Comment: admin panel is blank http://videomergerapp.com/andios

Comment: i refreshed cache and session using ssh commands

Comment: i changed database, post your comment ans answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Solution 1 :** Disable Compiler
Go to System -> Tools -> Compilation and Disable you Compiler and clear/flush magento cache data. In most of the cases this would solve the issue.

**Solution 2 :** Improve PHP Memory Limit
If you can access php.ini OR use .htaccess in the root OR edit index.php add below line right after `ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);`

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```